# How do I compare two hashes using SHA256Managed?

Tags: c#, hash

I can hash my user-entered password, but I'm unable to find out how to compare the stored hash and the new hash for a user-entered password.

This is my hashing code:

```
public static string CalculateHash(string clearTextPassword, string salt)
{
    //Convert the salted password to a byte array
    byte[] saltedHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearTextPassword + salt);

    //Use hash algorithm to calulate hash
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedHashBytes);

    //Return the hash as a base64 encoded string to be compared and stored
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

How do I compare two hashes to validate a password?

Comment: Just do an `==` on the two hashes, remember they're strings. There are better, more secure solutions, but this is too complex if you're just using SHA256. BTW, I'd recommend you to switch to SHA512

Comment: the simple `==` is vulnerable to a timing attack. It's typical to do a bitwise comparison that iterates through every single bit rather than stopping at the first non-match, so that the time it takes to calculate does not depend on how many matching bits there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should store salt with the hashed value.

Next, when user trying to authenticate with some `login` and `password` you can use next scenario:

1. Retrieve user data from database by Login (for example, `GetUser(login)`). User class should contains login, hashed password and salt.
2. If there is no user with that login, then fail authentication. Else execute `CalculateHash()` with `password` and salt from the User class retrieved on previous step.
3. Compare 2 strings: first is hashed password from User class and second from the `CalculateHash()` method. If hashes are equals then user successfully authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

You stored both the hash and the salt, right?

Now when the user tries to log in, you can run your method again using the salt you stored, and the output of your method should match hash stored in your database.